# dot (.) in HTML is misplaced

Tags: html, arabic, hebrew, persian, farsi

I am working with some Right to Left languages in HTML and the dot at the end of the sentence is always misplaced in browser. It looks fine in text editor but I cannot get the dot to go all the way at the end of the sentence when shown in browser. I tried sublime text and atom but no luck.

Number 1 and 2 shows the wrong place where the dot appears, and the arrow shows where it should actually be(the end of the sentence)!

[image]

In text editor its place is right!
[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example, please?

Comment: can you show your sample?

Comment: try `<p dir='rtl'>جهت نمايش نقطه.</p>`

Comment: well this was interesting and a good solution. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

That means that the test direction is set left-to-right instead of right-to-left. Try setting the CSS style:

```
direction: rtl;
```

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp .

Comment: This was bugging me for a long time. We had wysiwyg input box where users entered text and period kept moving. Changing the CSS fixed this! This can be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of the text editor you are using..
My suggestion is " use **Jquery** to remove all the styling in the FrontEnd" or any other inline styling.

If doesn't works for you then please share the link.

Answer (score 0):

for dot in Arabic for html just put this code in html  instead of dot

```
"&#1748;"
```

example

Arabic Text without dot ۔